# Why do so many diesel engines have problems with aluminum oxide in the cooling systems?

Tags: cooling-system, diesel

I have a bad case of aluminum oxide contamination in my 98 Mazda 626's cooling system.  While [researching the subject](https://aviondemand.com/insider/cooling-system-contamination-repeat-component-failure-requires-heroic-efforts/), and [filtration solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015RC3X4), I noticed that this type of problem is very common among many diesel engines, to the extent that many come with coolant filters as standard equipment, and after-market coolant filtration solutions [are widely available](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dautomotive&field-keywords=coolant%20filter%20kit).

Why is this such a common problem among many diesel engines and what specifically causes it?

Comment: I have owned VW diesels since 1977, and have not had this problem.  If aluminum oxide was in any quantity in the coolant, I would expect premature water pump failure.